# is sqlite is better or plist is better to save and edit items

Tags: iphone

i am trying to develop a simple application like shopping list.

for that i have 20 categories in that 250 item names.

for that i found two ways to save these item names and it's respective values one is using sqlite data base,another one is plist.

and i need to edit these item quantity and need to add new item to category.

for that which way is better for  my application.

experts who have familiar with sqlite data base and plist can suggest which way is better.

thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that SQLite is the better tool for this job, especially when the data grows. That's because with a PList, you have to completely load it into memory whereas with SQLite you only fetch the data you need. Of course, programming for SQLite is a little bit more work but if you encapsulate that in a class it can be as easy to use later on.

Answer (score 0):

Using of SQLite would be suggested.

If you are doing more transaction over the database then use SQLite instead of plits.

If it is client- server modal, have a database of SQL or Oracle at the back end. Store the data which is frequently used at the client side using SQLite ans sync it regularly with the database

regarding sqlite tutorial 
http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/